# on() with click event does nothing

Tags: jquery

I have a div with an id of "close" inside a dynamically created div with an id of "box". The following code is meant to do something whenever the user clicks on close.

```
$('#box').on('click','#close',function(){
    alert(1); // Test to see if the click works
});
```

I'm using the Big Cartel CMS and if I click close in the "live preview mode", it seems to work fine, but whenever I actually publish the site and view it normally, it does absolutely nothing - no errors - nada.

Markup & CSS, just in case:

```
<div id="box"> <!-- Dynamically loaded -->
    <div id="close"></div>
    <h2 id="name"></h2>
    <div id="description">
        <p>blah...</p>
    </div>
</div>

#close{
    background: url(image-path);
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 12px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `$('#box')` should be replaced by the closest previous STATIC content on the webpage.

Comment: Is the *box* div part of the DOM at the point you are binding the click event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is because `#box` is also dynamic. You need the primary selector to be an element which is available when the page is loaded.

A primary candidate would be the element in to which you are loading `#box`.

Comment: Your fiddle is flawed because it has `#box` available onload. The OPs code does not.

Comment: Boy, do I feel daft - I was trying to narrow down the DOM traversal. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to hook to an existant element, not the dynamically created one:

```
$(document).on('click','#box #close',function(){
    alert(1); // Test to see if the click works
});
```

EDIT: better solution to NOT hook to the document :) avoids the dom traversal.

```
$("#boxesparentid").on('click','#close',function(){
    alert(1); // Test to see if the click works
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use event delegation (for example using `.on` the way you are) you are binding an event to an element that is *higher* up in the `DOM` and then checking every event that bubbles up to see if it matches the selector. The important part to realize is that you need to make sure that the element you are binding to currently exists in the DOM (the one that bubbles up doesn't need to be).

In your case since *box* is also dynamic you event isn't bound to anything, you can instead bind to the document which exists or any higher level element that is currently in the `DOM`

For example

```
$(document).on('click','#close',function(){
    alert(1); // Test to see if the click works
});
```